# Accessing 2 tables with repository

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, repository

in my ASP.NET MVC app I have 3 tables:
Employees (id, name, surname, departmentId, regionId)
Departments (id, name)
Regions (id, name)

I need a form in create view, where I will have surname of employee + selectlist with departments (names) + selectlist with regions (names)

so my ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSurname { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> regions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> departments { get; set; }
}
```

Get Employees method (similarly Regions and Departments) in repository:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        _db.Database.Log = message => Trace.WriteLine(message);
        var employees = _db.Employees.AsNoTracking();
        return employees;
    }
```

LINQ in controller:

```
var employees = _repo.GetEmployees();
var regions = _repo.GetRegions();
var departments = _repo.GetDepartments();

IEnumerable<EmployeeVM> vm =
            from employee in employees
            join region in regions
            on employee.regionId equals region.Id into something
            select...
```

and there are 2 questions:

1. Is this proper declaration for my VM?
2. How to write linq syntax after "..." or is it bad already?

Comment: If you creating an employee, then you model would contain properties for your employee `name`, `surname`, `departmentId`, `regionId` (not a collection of `Employee` and it would contain 2 `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties for the collections of regions and departments

Comment: @StephenMuecke edited VM in my question, is it proper now?still what about LINQ expression?

Comment: You do not need to access `employees` to create a new `Employee` and the only queries you need are to generate the `SelectList`'s for the dropdowns - e.g. `EmployeeVM model = new .EmployeeVM() { departments = new SelectList(db.departments, "Id", "Name"), regions = ....}; return View(model);`